# Is it possible to use std::string in a program as part of if else statement

Tags: c++, c, stdstring

```
 if(condition)
    {
      std::string interface = string1;
    }
    else
    {
      std::string interface = string2;
    }
```

Can someon let me know if this is possible in a C program.

Comment: std::string is part of the standard C++ library, and hence cannot be used in a C program but only in a C++ program. But if you are programming in C++, then yes this can be done.

Comment: It is possible in C++. But what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in C++, but in your code sample, `interface` exists only in the limited scope of each block of the `if-else`. If you want to instantiate a string based on some condition, you can use the conditional operator:

```
std::string interface = condition ? string1 : string2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all std::string can be used only in a C++ program.

Second, if you declare like you did, then you have two variables whose scope is enclosed within the `then` part of `if` and the `else` part of `if` respectively:

```
if(condition)
    {
      // variable scope start
      std::string interface = string1;
      // variable scope end. beyond this point, the variable interface no longer exist.
    }
    else
    {
      // variable scope start (the old variable interface no longer exists. this is a new variable
      std::string interface = string2;
      // variable scope end.
    }
// at this point none of the variable exist anymore.
```

what you should do is:

```
std::string interface;
if (condition) {
  interface = string1;
} else {
  interface = string2;
}
```

or, as @juanchopanza said:

> std::string interface = condition ? string1 : string2;

Answer (score 0):

As it was said here it is possible in C++ but not in C because C has no type std::string. Also your example has no greate sense because each variable interface will alive only within corresponding compound statements and outside the if-else statement it will not be accessible.

In C you should use character arrays and standard function strcpy. For example

```
char interface[20];

 if(condition)
    {
      strcpy( interface, string1 );
    }
    else
    {
      strcpy( interface, string2 );
    }
```

provided that variable interface is large enough to accomodate character arrays string1 or string2